# one_loop is slower than two_loop in k-nearest method in CS231n

Tags: python

I am doing an [assignment in CS231n](http://cs231n.github.io/assignments2018/assignment1/).

I am wondering why `one_loop` is slower than `two_loop`.

My result is like this:

[image]

My code is this:

```
def compute_distances_one_loop(self, X):
  num_test = X.shape[0]
  num_train = self.X_train.shape[0]
  dists = np.zeros((num_test, num_train))
  for i in range(num_test):
    dists[i] = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(X[i] - self.X_train), axis=1))

  return dists

def compute_distances_two_loops(self, X):
   num_test = X.shape[0]
   num_train = self.X_train.shape[0]
   dists = np.zeros((num_test, num_train))
   for i in range(num_test):
      for j in range(num_train):
         dists[i, j] = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(X[i] - self.X_train[j])))
   return dists
```

I am executing the code in a Jupyter notebook.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My situation is more extreme than yours! I use [np.linalg.norm ](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html) to slove L2 distance. two loops:20s one loop:60s I check the reason why one loop is slow may be `X[i] - self.X_train`. You can find some good solutions on github such as https://github.com/cthorey/CS231